# Recommendation for unit-testing of annotations spock

Tags: grails, spock

What is the recommendation for test of annotation within my own plugin module for grails. Here is my thoughts?

1. Have a `subfolder` of `Test classes` within the `unittest` folder where my new annotations are present.
2. Deprecate the `TestClasses`

Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't really test annotations because they don't contain behavior.  You might test the effects of having an annotation on a certain class but how you do that would depend on knowing what the annotation is being used for.

Comment: One common approach that makes sense is to have classes defined in your test folder which are marked with the annotation and then have a unit test that asserts that the expected effects have been imposed on that class.  Whether or not that approach makes sense for your scenario would require knowing more about your annotation(s).